# neo4j: set different properties based on existing properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to set new properties based on existing properties. The existing nodes have the following properties:

`minTempC`, `maxTempC`

New properties should be set if the following conditions are met:

`minTempC < 0` set the property `frosstag = true`

`maxTempC < 0` set the property `eistag = true`

`maxTempC >= 30` set the property `heissertag = true`

The existing nodes can meet one, multiple or none of the conditions.

My cypher right now is:

```
//Eistag
MATCH (d:Data)
WHERE d.maxtempC < 0
SET d += {eistag:true}

//Frosttag
MATCH (d:Data)
WHERE d.mintempC < 0 
SET d += {frosttag:true}

//Heisser Tag
MATCH (d:Data)
WHERE d.maxtempC >= 30
SET d += {heisserTag:true}
```

Is there a way to combine these three? I have several other properties that have to be set and writing these `SET` clauses over and over again seems a little bit tedious. I thought of using a `CASE`expression, but I am new to neo4j and must confess that I have no idea how to built such a expression.

Thank you in advance for yout tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` in an expression, so the following should help:

```
MATCH (d:Data)
SET 
d.eistag = CASE WHEN d.minTempC < 0 THEN true END,
d.frosttag = CASE WHEN d.maxTempC < 0 THEN true END,
d.heisserTag = CASE WHEN d.maxTempC >= 0 THEN true END
```

Note that if the condition is false, a `null` is returned from `CASE WHEN`. Setting a property to a `null` value results in not setting this property.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.